# Labelling polygon using QGIS?

Tags: polygon, labeling, qgis-2.4

Using QGIS 2.4, I have tried labeling a polygon using the layer properties>label function but it doesn't show my label.

How and where do I type the text I want and get it to show?

Comment: needs to be in an attribute of your feature.

Comment: what is the attribute name that holds the label content?

Comment: I created a polygon.  The attribute table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The layer you are trying to label must have at least one attribute field populated with data. You can then turn on labelling in Layer Properties and select which attribute field to use for your labels.

Have a look here as well: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html

Comment: How do I insert data into an attribute field?  The training manual does not help as "Click on the places layer in the Layers list" makes no sense.  Where is the "layers list"?

Comment: Have a look here for a description of the layers list: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/introduction/overview.html Think of it as the contents of your map. It is typically in the left pane. To insert data to a field you must first make the layer editable. I suggest you take a look in the QGIS tutorial from the start as it is well documented and well suited for beginners.